# Selective XML indexing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, indexing

I have a table that has thousands of rows that has the following data in the column named OldValue:

```
<attendance xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CalendarId>100</CalendarId>
  <PeriodId>1019</PeriodId>
  <PersonId>10457</PersonId>
  <Date>2012-01-04 00:00:00</Date>
  <ExcuseId>884</ExcuseId>
</attendance>
```

I am trying to set a selective xml index.  Here is what I have done so far:

Creating the selective XML Index:

```
CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX sxi_Test ON [dbo].[mytable](OldValue)
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as yming)
FOR
(    
pathWH2 = '/yming:Attendance/PersonId' AS XQUERY 'xs:string' SINGLETON
);
GO
```

Querying the index always returns 0 rows:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as yming)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE OldValue.exist(N'(/yming:Attendance/yming:PersonId[.=10457])') = 1
GO
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually stumble into a solution with anything involving XML namespaces in SQL, but this seems to work for me:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<attendance xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <CalendarId>100</CalendarId> <PeriodId>1019</PeriodId> <PersonId>10457</PersonId> <Date>2012-01-04 00:00:00</Date> <ExcuseId>884</ExcuseId> </attendance>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as yming)
SELECT @x.exist(N'(/attendance/PersonId[.=10457])')
GO
```